# Alternate method in referenced assembly when in debug mode using [Conditional("DEBUG")]

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

Im trying to make a method in an assembly that behaves differently when the calling assembly is in Debug configuration.

Specifically, I have a Mailer library that uses templates to create and send e-mails. Since I don't want to accidentally spam a client with debug mails I'm trying to make 2 versions of my `SendMail` method.

The idea is that in Debug mode `MailMessage.Recipients` will be cleared and a default mail address will be used instead (i.e. our own internal mail address). I would like this to be as transparent as possible, without requiring extra code or configuration on the calling side.

The problem is that the Mailer library gets built into a Nuget package and therefore is always in Release build.
I wanted to do something like this:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private void SetDebugMode(MailMessage mail)
    {
        mail.To.Clear();
        mail.CC.Clear();
        mail.Bcc.Clear();

        mail.To.Add("support@example.com");
        mail.Subject += " [DEBUG]";
    }

    public void SendMail()
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            [...]
            SetDebugMode(mail);
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
```

This doesnt work since the calling method is the SendMail method, which is in Release configuration.

Is there a way to use the same method call so the public interface remains the same but still get this functionality?
I guess the alternatives would be using an optional `isDebug = false` parameter or a config setting or something along those lines, but I'd prefer to do it without having to edit any other code outside this assembly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you rely of configuration? If the default SMTP server configuration is different between your environments, this should be good enough.

Comment: Yeah this is probably going to be the way to go, but the conditional attribute just seems like the cleanest solution (if it would actually work). I was just hoping it could be done without having to add any code to other projects, just to be able to debug something.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do:

```
#if DEBUG
  Mail.Subject += " [Debug]";
#endif
```

etc? so you have 1 function with additional code if its debug

or

if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) Mail.Subject += " [DEBUG]";

Comment: I highly dislike these preprocessor directives. Too often they can mask what code is and is not being called and one only finds that the build is broken when switching to a different configuration.

Comment: I tried that as well. The code after the #if DEBUG wont get compiled into the dll, whereas the Conditional attribute does get compiled, even if the assembly is in release.

Comment: True. I also have used the simple if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) Console.WriteLine("debug");

Comment: @Oded - In VS 2010 and above the code that won't be compiled is greyed out, how is that masking what code will get called?

Comment: @BugFinder: A compile build and an attached debugger are two different things. You can even attach a debugger to a release build.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that yet! Unfortunately Debugger.IsAttached won't work either, since we also run test builds on our test server which won't have a debugger attached, but still shouldn't send out mails.

Comment: @Guido - Why would you want code that can't be called compiled into your release assembly?

Comment: You can be calling some functions in these blocks. It will not be clear whether a function is or is not being called.

Comment: @Kevin They can be called, as long as the build is in Debug configuration, but the function will be ignored as soon as you go to Release config.

Comment: OK, Then I fail to understand how your computer should know it should be sending the debug'd message not the real ones..

Comment: @BugFinder The conditional attribute checks if the caller is in debug mode and it works fine as long as I call that method directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
    #if DEBUG
    private void SetDebugMode(MailMessage mail) {
        mail.To.Clear();
        mail.CC.Clear();
        mail.Bcc.Clear();
        mail.To.Add("support@example.com");
        mail.Subject += " [DEBUG]"; }
    #endif

    public void SendMail() {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()) {
        [...]
        #if DEBUG
        SetDebugMode(mail);
        #endif
        smtp.Send(mail); } }
```

This way the SetDebugMode method and the call to it only get compiled and used when in debug mode.